# facelet - img tag

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

Questions:

- how can I use img tag in facelet java ?

I've tried using the html tag and it fails. Thanks first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Facelets are just XHTML mark-up, so you can use the standard HTML image tag if you want, provided it's well formed e.g.

```
<img src="myfolder/myimage.jpg"/>
```

Or you can use a JSF component to render it e.g.

```
<h:graphicImage library="myfolder" name="myimage.jpg"/>
```